# What does the highlight color mean in the java frame debugger?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

(IC-132.556)

[image: What does the highlight colors mean in the java frame debugger?]

(frame 617 717 43 are highlighted from the rest?)

[image: What does the highlight colors mean in the java frame debugger?]

(debug info found)

[image: What does the highlight colors mean in the java frame debugger?]

(intelligent recursion analysis)

Answer (score 1):

Click on one and find out! It means that the local variables debug info is not available!

[image]

Comment: For me it seems that they are available? (added a new screen)

Comment: Oh ok, well not sure then, every time mine are highlighted is because they aren't!

Answer (score 1):

It is the so-called [Intelligent recursion analysis](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/compiler.html#link16).

> This feature simplifies debugging with highlighting of recursive calls in Frames view, letting you easily analyze them and find probable cases of infinite recursion.

Comment: I think the intelligent recursion analysis is highlighted differently? (added new screen)

Answer (score 0):

### Those are **non-project files**.

Go to **Settings - Appearance & Behavior - File Colors**. For me, non-project files are set to brown, and tests are set to green. I think you may also define colors for other file types.

From [IntelliJ - File Colors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scope.html):

> Use this page to set different background colors for distinguishing between project files, folders, and packages of [specific scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scope.html).

[image]

Reference: [IntelliJ Ideea background color for External Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951342/intellij-ideea-background-color-for-external-libraries).