# IntelliJ Idea background color for External Libraries

Tags: intellij-idea, colors

How can I change the color (that dark blue) in IntelliJ Idea to External libraries background?
I tried to find that out in Settings -Editor - Color & Fonts but I didn't find out the background color of External Libraries...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> File Colors. You will see various file scopes defined there. By default, there are only two - "Non-Project Files" and "Tests".

You'll need to change the colors for the non-project files scope. Also make sure to check any custom-defined scopes.

---

NOTE: Your screenshot makes me think that it is a mixture between the Normal and Darcula themes provided by IDEA. Have you been switching between them? Fully applying the changes needs a restart, and the IDE looks weird until you do. If that is the case, try restarting the IDE first to see if it fixes the problem.